# Differing code results based on module imported? (elementtree)

Tags: python, xml, elementtree

Python 2.7 I used the bundled elementtree module to write some code.

```
commands = root.findall('{http://clish.sourceforge.net/XMLSchema}'
                        'VIEW/{http://clish.sourceforge.net/XMLSchema}COMMAND')
tree_list = []

for command in commands:
    tree_list.append(list(command.iter()))
```

Now later on in the code I did:

```
for command in commands:
    for i in command:
         if "CONFIG" in str(i):
             command.remove(i)
    tree_list.append(list(command.iter()))
```

and this worked fine. However I then only imported `ElementTree.py` on it's own for a minimal install, instead of `import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET`.
For some reason the functionality now differs. The second time I loop through `commands` I note that there is nothing to loop through, it's empty. So before the second loop I now have to do this code again to "refill" `commands`:

```
commands = root.findall('{http://clish.sourceforge.net/XMLSchema}'
                            'VIEW/{http://clish.sourceforge.net/XMLSchema}COMMAND')
```

I am wondering why this is so? How is the imported module affecting this? Perhaps importing a differing `elementtree.py` did this, but why is it affecting a generator?

Answer (score 1):

The implementation of `findall` in the standard library always returns a list, if you want an iterator use the `iterfind` method.  I'm not sure which external version of `ElementTree` you have been working with, but it appears that [this version](http://home.badc.rl.ac.uk/kershaw.bak/leonardo-0.7b1/lib/leonardo/thirdParty/ElementTree.py) returns an iterator from `findall` instead of a list.  It would probably be safer to call `list` on the returned value:

```
commands = list(root.findall('{http://clish.sourceforge.net/XMLSchema}'
                'VIEW/{http://clish.sourceforge.net/XMLSchema}COMMAND'))
```

If that is what you require, and it will work with both `ElementTree` implementations.